# Reloading tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow

I have two separate tensorflow processes, one which is training a model and writing out graph_defs with `tensorflow.python.client.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants`, and another which is reading the graph_def with `tensorflow.import_graph_def`. I would like the second process to periodically reload the graph_def as it gets updated by the first process. Unfortunately, it appears that every subsequent time I read the graph_def the old one is still used, even if I close the current session and create a new one. I have also tried wrapping the `import_graph_def call` with `sess.graph.as_default()`, to no avail. Here is my current graph_def loading code:

```
if self.sess is not None:
    self.sess.close()
self.sess = tf.Session()

graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with open(self.graph_path, 'rb') as f:
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
with self.sess.graph.as_default():
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that, when you create a `tf.Session` with no arguments, it uses the **current default graph**. Assuming you don't create a `tf.Graph` anywhere else in your code, you get the global default graph that is created when the process starts, and this is shared between all of the sessions. As a result, `with self.sess.graph.as_default():` has no effect.

It's hard to recommend a new structure from the snippet you showed in the question—in particular, I've no idea about how you created the previous graph, or what the class structure is—but one possibility would be to replace the `self.sess = tf.Session()` with the following:

```
self.sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())  # Creates a new graph for the session.
```

Now the `with self.sess.graph.as_default():` will use the graph that was created for the session, and your program should have the intended effect.

A somewhat preferable (to me, at least) alternative would be to build the graph explicitly:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as imported_graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, ...)

sess = tf.Session(graph=imported_graph)
```

Comment: Since the graphs I'm using all have the same structure, only different weights, I think it would be more efficient to load the graph once and then load only the variables using something like `Saver.restore()`. I tried this and it appears that subsequent calls to Saver.restore() have no effect. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it should work. Multiple calls to `Saver.restore()` should have effect, so I'm not sure what's going wrong though. Are you using a single graph and a single `tf.Session`?

Comment: It appears that I was mistaken, multiple calls to `restore()` do have effect, and they are quite a bit faster than loading the whole graph (so fast that it made me think they weren't doing anything!). I think I'm going to just `restore()` from now on, unless in the future I need to run the graph in C++ again.